# How to implement Is_Empty in Ada, and how to make an empty string with own discriminant string type?

Tags: string, ada, is-empty

I have a home project in Ada, where have to make a J_String package, but can't figure out Is_Empty method, and i can't make an empty string neither with my type.
I have the following .ads:

```
package J_String_Pkg is
type J_String(Size: Positive) is private;
function Is_Empty(S : J_String) return Boolean;
private
    type J_String(Size: Positive) is record
        Components: String(1..Size);
    end record;
```

and my .adb:

```
function Create(Str : String) return J_String is --Just creates a J_String
    Jstr: J_String(Str'Length);
begin   
    Jstr.Components := Str;
    return Jstr;
end Create;

function Is_Empty(S : J_String) return Boolean is
--returns true if and only if length is 0
begin
    return S.Components'Length = 0;
end Is_Empty;
```

Way i use it:

```
jstr1: J_String(5) := Create("apple");
--tried empty string as:
jstr2: J_String := Create("");
```

My discriminant is Positive atm, i've tried with Integer and String(0..Size) in my record but it didn't work i get constraint_errors. I would happy if this can be solved with nothing drastical change, because i've finished with almost all 20+ methods that i must implement, except this one. Thanks for every help!

Comment: If the `Size` discriminant was Natural rather than Positive, then 0 would be a valid value for it, and the rest of the design including empty Jstrings would follow naturally. As it is you cannot declare a Size of zero, a null range for the array  i.e. (1 .. 0) nor an empty JString.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i understand! :)